# Docker compose multiple dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm currently working on a maven project where I would like to have 2 docker container where one launch all the tests and the other compile the project if all the tests succeed.

The problem is that both containers launch the prod dockerfile.

So my question is why after pointing each Dockerfile in the docker compose they both start on the prod one

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: cuisine
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
          timeout: 20s
          retries: 10
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql-dump/cuisine:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  test:
    container_name: java-test
    image: spring-boot
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/test/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
      - "5005:5005"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
       - ${APPLICATION_ROOT_FOLDER}:/usr/src/mymaven
       - ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FOLDER}:/root/.m2
  java:
    container_name: java
    image: spring-boot
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/prod/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
      - "5006:5006"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
       - ${APPLICATION_ROOT_FOLDER}:/usr/src/mymaven
       - ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FOLDER}:/root/.m2
volumes:
  mysql:
```

Comment: have you tried docker-compose up --build?

Comment: Yes I did, still doesn't work

Comment: you should define your image section with different names. For example one could be 
image: spring-boot and the other one image: spring-boot-test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have both `build:` and `image:` on your services, the built image is tagged with the `image:` name. You have the same `image:` name for both services, so the last one to be built 'wins' and is run for both services. Remove the `image:` name for both.